# Are germanium MOSFETS and Heterojunction Bipolar Transistors commercially available?

Tags: mosfet

I've read a great deal about the development of Germanium field effect transistors and HJTs but are they actually been manufactured commercially? If so where can I buy them? I already know where to get Germanium diodes but I want MOSFETs if they're available.

Comment: You say germanium heterojunction, but that implies another material. Silicon germanium HBT IC processes have been available for a while, and there are commercially available parts with them.

Comment: And why, exactly, do you _want_ Ge MOSFETs?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Because Ge has some very interesting properties that make it more useful than silicon for analog circuits. It has a higher electron mobility and lower barrier potential which is VERY useful for hardware random number generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer NO

These are still in the research/development phase and will not be available for purchase any time in the near future.  If you see them available for purchase, they are quite likely a scam or unreliable.  The only people I forsee selling these in the next 2 years also sell fake Persian rugs.

Comment: Does this also apply to Si-Ge heterojunction transistors too?

Comment: Yes, it should.